# TCP sockets connection becomes unreliable with SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have an app where a single client talks to a single server. Normally, the client does a single `connect`, and then calls `send` repeatedly, and there's no problem.

However, I need to do a version where the client sets up a connection for each individual `send` (a bit like HTTP with and without `keep-alive`). In this version, the client calls `socket`, `connect`, `send` once, and then `close`.

The problem with this is that I very quickly run out of ephemeral client ports, and the `connect` fails. To get around this I call `setsockopt` with `SO_REUSEADDR`, and then bind to port 0, before calling `connect` (see [here](https://idea.popcount.org/2014-04-03-bind-before-connect/), for example).

This works, except that the TCP connection is no longer reliable. I get occasional incorrect data, presumably because there's still data around when the TCP connection is closed.

Is there any way to make this reliable (and fast)? `shutdown` before `close` doesn't help. Maybe I can get `select` to tell me if the socket is ready for output, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: How often do you call `send`? TCP isn't really designed for `connect` - `send` - `close` repeat cycles, as the TCP setup and tear-down can be expensive. Could you perhaps give us a *reason* for why you need this? Why can't you use `connect` - `send` - `send` - ... - `close`? Perhaps you should consider using the unconnected UDP instead?

Comment: The end app occasionally sends bursts of high-frequency packets, but can also wait much longer between sends. It fails occassionally and is being re-written (from boost::asio to plain-old-C). The current code is a test to find out what's possible - if I have to `connect` once and keep the connection open, I'll do that, but I would like to be sure that's the only or best option. `connect`-`send`-`close` feels like it might be cleaner from the point of view of error recovery. Or not.

Comment: Remember that TCP is a *reliable* protocol. If there is an error the send or receive calls will tell you about it, and at that point you do error recovery (by disconnecting and retry to connect). As I said, connection setup and tear-down in TCP is expensive, old HTTP is really a bad example on how to use TCP in this regard.

Comment: You will have to keep the connection open, and lose your idea about what is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use TCP? If so, you will probably have to maintain an open connection and route your messages over that one connection.

There is [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol), which may be a good fit for your use case - a reliable datagram protocol:

> Like TCP, SCTP provides reliable, connection oriented data delivery with congestion control. Unlike TCP, SCTP also provides message bound‐ ary preservation, ordered and unordered message delivery, multi-stream‐ ing and multi-homing. Detection of data corruption, loss of data and duplication of data is achieved by using checksums and sequence numbers. A selective retransmission mechanism is applied to correct loss or corruption of data.